# Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping'[org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit4

I'm trying to run JUnit test but I got this error. I tried alot but didn't find the solution.I got this exceptions. I also tried to componentScan at test class :-@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.jitender.bookStore"}, excludeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = Configuration.class)}) but this also not work.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at com.jitender.bookStore.tests.CategoryTestCase.init(CategoryTestCase.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:534)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 31 more
```

Here is my configuration Files. WebConfig.java

```
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.webflow.config.AbstractFlowConfiguration;
import org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.ViewFactoryCreator;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices;
import org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutor;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages=("com.jitender.bookStore.controller"))
public class WebConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer{
   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
   @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
           registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
       }
   
   @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewrResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
       viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
       viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
       return viewResolver;
       
   }
```

CategoryTestCase Class :

```
public class CategoryTestCase {

    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
    
    @Autowired
    private static CategoryDAO categoryDao;

    @Autowired
    private BookCategory category;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.jitender.bookStore");
        
        context.refresh();
        categoryDao = (CategoryDAO) context.getBean("categoryDao");

    }
    
    @Test
    public void testaddCategory() {
        category = new BookCategory();
        category.setCategoryName("thriller");
        assertEquals("Successfully added a category",true, categoryDao.addCategory(category));
        
    }
    
}
```

CategoryDaoImpl Class:

```
package com.jitender.bookStore.daoImp;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.jitender.bookStore.dao.CategoryDAO;
import com.jitender.bookStore.model.BookCategory;

@Repository("categoryDao")
@Transactional
public class CategoryDaoImpl implements CategoryDAO {
    
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<BookCategory> categoryList() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from category", BookCategory.class).list();
    }

    @Override
    public Long addCategory(BookCategory category) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(category);
        return category.getCategoryId();
    }

}
```

Comment: It says no servlet context is set - try googling what could that be and how to set one in spring mic